# Yeoman won't recognize a generator installed globally or locally

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm very new to Node.JS and Yeoman and can't figure out what is wrong. I'm cloning the repo https://github.com/ypmits/ARrrrLib/tree/develop which contains what it seems to be a node.js node and a yeoman generator.

After cloning it I run `npm install` for installing dependencies but then I can't make to successfully run the generator. I've tried installing it globally navigating to the generator folder and running `npm link` but then the generator won't be listed by `yo` although the symlink is created.

Tried also running it locally with `yo .\generator-socialarlib` but the following errors are returned:

```
Error .\generator-socialarlib

Cannot find module 'C:\Programming\Spark\Testing\ARrrrLib-develop\generator-socialarlib\'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\environment.js
- C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\router.js
- C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js
```

Comment: I get the same. Did you manage to solve it?